# Table View & Function Declaration as well as Definition

Tags: database, postgresql

How to get:
  1 . table view Declaration as well as Definition in PostgreSQL.
  2 . table function Declaration as well as Definition in PostgreSQL.

Comment: What did you try before posting? What did not work about what you tried? What have you read/searched? Seriously.

Comment: Select * from information_schema.views c where c.table_name= 'gl_headers'

Comment: I Ran this sql but it gives definition not  declaration

Comment: Assuming you were trying to comment on my answer there ... you might want to edit your question and explain what you mean by "definition" and "declaration". The two are one and the same in SQL. In general your questions should include what you've tried, Pg version, error messages, your OS/distro if relevant, etc.

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW export.emp(
    id,
    company_id,
    period_id,
    )
AS
  SELECT
      emp.id,
      emp.company_id,
      emp.period_id   
  FROM
      emp;

I want id,company_id,period_id this column name with their order number from view export.emp

Answer (score 0):

1. `pg_dump -t table_or_view_name --schema-only` works for tables or views. For views only, `pg_get_viewdev('viewname')`.
2. `pg_dump`, or use `pg_get_functiondef('funcname')`

For column information, you can query the `information_schema.columns` view (for tables/views), or `information_schema.routines` and `information_schema.parameters` for functions.